# Session value to TextBox Value

Tags: asp.net

How to call a Session and use it as a value of Text Box Form. I am using asp.net

```
<form id="frmLog" name="frmLog" method="post" action="/Page/">
<input type="text" name="UserId" value="<%=Sessiopn["UserID"] %>">" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct it to this. You have a typing mistake.

```
<input type="text" name="UserId" value="<%=Session["UserID"] %>" />
```

Comment: You have an extra >" in your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have error on variable name (without p)

Sessiopn -> Session